# RxJava and list of `Single` observable

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm new in `RxJava` so I still have many doubts.

I'm creating this:

```
    @Override
    public Single<Result> saveUser(final User user) {

    return Single.create(new Single.OnSubscribe<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final SingleSubscriber<? super Result> singleSubscriber) {

            if(user.isValid()){
              save(user);
              //Set result ok
              singleSubscriber.onSuccess(result);
            } else {
                //This sets an error.
                singleSubscriber.onError(error);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Depending of the success of the operation, the `Single` emits it's data and who is subscribed receives the data.

The problem now is that at some point I need to store a list of users. Something like:

```
public void saveUsers(List<User> listOfUsers){
    for (User user : listOfUsers) {
        saveUser(user);
    }
}
```

How can I create an `Single` so I can be subscribed to the initial `Single`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather create flatmap out of observable list.

```
public void saveUsers(List<User> listOfUsers){
    Observable.from(listOfUsers).flatMap((User user)->{
         if(user.isValid()){
           save(user);
           //Set result ok
           return Observable.just(result);
         }else
           return Observable.error(new RuntimeException("..."));
   }).retry(2);
}
```

If you make your `saveUsers` method blocking, call `Observable#toBlocking`.